# TSQL: How to add automatically select columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a problem and can't solve it. Furthermore I can't find an answer anywhere in the internet.

Simplified I have a big table with coloumns, where values to products with an ID are stored by year:

- year
- id
- value

In my stored procedure the attributes for getting information are:

- @year
- @id

If you want to get information about more than one product, you can use a comma-seperated list of product-ids like ('654654,543543,987987').

My TSQL should be like this:

```
select year, 
    sum(case when id = @id[1] then value), 
    sum(case when id = @id[2] then value), 
    [...]
from table myTable
where year = @year 
group by year 
order by year
```

What I want to do is iterate throught the comma-seperated ids and for each id, I want to add a new select attribut like this (sum(case when id = @id[x] then value).

Can you help me with this problems? Any suggestions to solve it?!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Consider using a table-valued parameter instead of a comma-separated list. Also, you should be aiming to get your results back in a different format (PIVOT results aren't good at being dynamic; they want a fixed number of columns too!). Leave the pivot-y bit to your front-end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) operation could simplify the query.

But, anyway, it seems that the only way to construct such a query is to use dynamic SQL.

```
DECLARE
    @Ids NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @stmt NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @Ids = '1,2'

-- Transform Ids into the format PIVOT understands - with square brackets.
-- Primitive way, to not overcomplicate sample.
SET @Ids = '[' + REPLACE(@Ids, ',', '], [') + ']'
PRINT @Ids -- [1], [2]

SET @Stmt = '
  SELECT *
  FROM Products as p
  PIVOT 
  (
      SUM(p.Value)
      FOR p.Id IN (' + @Ids + ')
  ) AS t
  ORDER BY Year'


EXEC sp_executesql @Stmt
```

If you need more accurate way of splitting a comma separated list into an array (table), please see this [article](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/faking-arrays-in-transact-sql/) for details.

This example is available on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/53905/22)

Answer (score 0):

As you are using stored procedure, you can use [sp_executesql](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) to executed dynimically build SQL statement.

So, you have to iterate over the CSV like this:

```
DECLARE @List NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'1001,dada,1002,1003'
DECLARE @ProductsID TABLE ( [ID] BIGINT )


DECLARE @XML xml = N'<r><![CDATA[' + REPLACE(@List, ',', ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + ']]></r>'

INSERT INTO @ProductsID ([ID])
SELECT DISTINCT CAST(Tbl.Col.value('.', 'float') AS bigint)
FROM @xml.nodes('//r') Tbl(Col)
WHERE ISNUMERIC(Tbl.Col.value('.', 'varchar(max)')) = 1

SELECT [ID] FROM @ProductsID
```

Then, having a table with the ID to dynamically build you SQL statement and execute it.